# PHP oci8 installation fails on Ubuntu 18

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, oci8, php-7.3

I'm trying to install oci8 through pecl, following [this link](https://vfac.fr/blog/how-to-install-oracle-client-instant-oci8-on-linux). I successfully installed oci8 following these steps last year, before the release of php8.0.
This is my configuration:

- Ubuntu 18.04.5
- PHP7.3
- Oracle instantclient Version 19.10 (Also tried with 21.1 and 19.8-the last version that worked for me, before php8.0 release)

This is what I've done after unzipping the instantclient:

```
sudo echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_10 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf
sudo ldconfig
sudo apt install php7.3-dev php-pear build-essential libaio1
echo "instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_10" | pecl install oci8-2.2.0
```

You can find the output of `echo "instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_10" | pecl install oci8-2.2.0` below:

```
downloading oci8-2.2.0.tgz ...
Starting to download oci8-2.2.0.tgz (196,449 bytes)
.........................................done: 196,449 bytes
11 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20200930
Zend Module Api No:      20200930
Zend Extension Api No:   420200930
Please provide the path to the ORACLE_HOME directory. Use 'instantclient,/path/to/instant/client/lib' if you're compiling with Oracle Instant Client [autodetect] : building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0
running: /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-oci8=instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_10
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/20200930
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php/20200930
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking for Oracle Database OCI8 support... yes, shared
checking PHP version... 8.0.3, ok
checking OCI8 DTrace support... no
checking size of long int... 8
checking checking if we're on a 64-bit platform... yes
checking Oracle Instant Client directory... /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_10
checking Oracle Instant Client SDK header directory... /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_10/sdk/include
checking Oracle Instant Client library version compatibility... 19.1
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gawk... (cached) nawk
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: patching config.h.in
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib -I/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_10/sdk/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2    -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8.c -o oci8.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib -I/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_10/sdk/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oci8.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib -I/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_10/sdk/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2    -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_lob.c -o oci8_lob.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib -I/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_10/sdk/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_lob.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oci8_lob.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib -I/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_10/sdk/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2    -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_statement.c -o oci8_statement.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib -I/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_10/sdk/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_statement.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oci8_statement.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib -I/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_10/sdk/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2    -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_collection.c -o oci8_collection.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib -I/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_10/sdk/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_collection.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oci8_collection.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib -I/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_10/sdk/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2    -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_interface.c -o oci8_interface.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootF6jqsy/oci8-2.2.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib -I/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_10/sdk/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_interface.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oci8_interface.o
/tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_interface.c: In function ‘zif_oci_fetch_all’:
/tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_interface.c:1476:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Z_PARAM_ZVAL_DEREF_EX’; did you mean ‘Z_PARAM_ZVAL_EX’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   Z_PARAM_ZVAL_DEREF_EX(array, 0, 1)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   Z_PARAM_ZVAL_EX
In file included from /usr/include/php/20200930/main/php.h:36:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_interface.c:32:
/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend/zend_API.h:1349:2: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘_optional’
  _optional = 1;
  ^
/tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_interface.c:1477:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘Z_PARAM_OPTIONAL’
   Z_PARAM_OPTIONAL
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Makefile:219: recipe for target 'oci8_interface.lo' failed
make: *** [oci8_interface.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

I've searched online, but [this](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4302037/activando-oci8-version-2-2-0-en-opensuse-leap-15) is the only answer I can find regarding my problem.

Edit: On further inspection, not even the answer above addresses my issue. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check you have the right PHP header files - the 20200930 in the path looks suspicious.  Even on Ubuntu 20.20, the default PHP 7.4 installs headers into `/usr/include/php/20190902` so why are your headers for 7.3 in `/usr/include/php/20200930`?

If this is not the problem, check if your compiler is too old? Try the 'phpize' install (see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php)) and add compile options to see what the macros are expanding to.  Try grabbing the OCI8 directory from a PHP source bundle matching you version (and use the `phpize` method to install).  The problem won't be Instant Client.

Finally, why not upgrade Ubuntu and/or PHP?

Comment: That was it! It turns out I had also installed phpmyadmin which now runs under PHP8.0. Either that or installing php-dev without stating the PHP version, which installed php8.0-dev by default. Both these actions create headers in `/usr/include/php/20200930`.
I had to completely purge PHP8.0 and then the oci8 installation worked like a charm.
Yes, I'll consider upgrading PHP in the future. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, same problem in my case. I work on 7.4 but php 8 is installed and it turns problem out.

Comment: I had 7.4 and 8.1 installed on 20.04, it was set to 7.4 but I installed php-dev which defaults to php8.1. Then for the sake I completely removed php 8.1, then installed php7.4-dev. After that, the installation of oci8-2.0.0 was successfull.

Answer (score 2):

If you have several PHP installs you should change all three `php` `phpize` and `php-conf` to the wanted version:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.3
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.3
```

After that `pecl install oci8-2.2.0` works like expected and installs to PHP7.3

Answer (score 1):

Something that worked for me with `oci8` was to trick `pecl` into using the preferred version of include files by aliasing the directory, then after compilation, moving the library to the correct directory:

```sh
$ cd /usr/include/php/                       -- create the alias
$ sudo mv 20210902 x20210902
$ sudo ln -s 20190902 20210902
$ sudo pecl install oci8-2.2.0               -- build the library
instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_8
...
Installing '/usr/lib/php/20210902/oci8.so'   -- success!
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/oci8-2.2.0
$ cd /usr/lib/php/20210902/                  -- move the library
$ sudo mv oci8.so ../20190902/
$ cd /usr/include/php/                       -- undo the alias
$ sudo rm 20190902
$ sudo mv x20210902 20210902
```

After setting up the `ini` and other files and restarting Apache, the error log showed no errors, and `phpinfo()` showed an `oci8` section.